# Could you explain why the iron (ii) carbonate re-dissolves and how this can be described as an acid/base reaction , by mixing FeSO4 and Fe2+ salts

Tags: acid-base

Iron(II) carbonate is insoluble but in class you might not have seen any solid. The precipitate often redissolves because the iron(II) sulphate has acid added to it. Can you explain why the carbonate redissolves and how this can be described as an acid/base reaction

I know little to nothing about the topic and have done quite a bit of research but I can't find a simple definition that I am able to understand

Comment: Welcome to the chemistry site of the StackExchange (SE) network.  Be aware that laconic, not elaborated questions are usually closed on the SE.  
The site expects that you include the compact summary of your related current knowledge, involving your conclusion of searching for existing related  info or answers. It would prevent others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself. Effort not shown may be considered as effort not done, possibly leading to the question closure. [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Ferrons carbonate $\ce{FeCO3(s)}$ is like calcium carbonate $\ce{CaCO3}$ : it is soluble in carbonic acid with formation of the hydrogenocarbonate ion $\ce{HCO3^-}$in a reaction : $$\ce{FeCO3(s) + H2CO3 -> Fe^{2+} + 2 HCO3^- \tag{1}}$$ This means that $\ce{Fe(HCO3)2}$ is soluble in water.

$\ce{FeCO3(s)}$ can also be dissolved by the weak acidity produced by the hydrolysis of the  $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ ions coming from $\ce{FeSO4}$ in water, according to the two equations ($2$) and ($3$)  : $$\ce{Fe^{2+} + H2O <=>  [Fe(OH)]^+ + H^+ \tag{2}}$$
$$\ce{FeCO3 + H^+ -> Fe^{2+} + HCO3^- \tag{3}}$$

Comment: $\ce{FeCO3}$ is an insoluble substance that does exist in water. $\ce{FeSO4}$ does not exist in solution, as it is soluble, and produces $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ ions and $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ ions. So the two reactions (1) and (3) of $\ce{FeCO3(s)}$ with acids do not occur with $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ as it would mean that $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ produces $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ which is absurd.